# How to move emails between Gmail accounts?

Tags: gmail, imap

I have a couple of Gmail accounts (one personal Gmail and a couple of work Google Apps accounts) and sometimes, I mistakenly send an email and start a conversation from the wrong account. What is the best way to move it to where it belongs?

The two ways I am using at the moment but am not entirely happy about:

1. **Forward the email**. That is not really moving the original emails from one inbox to another, it creates a new mail with the original conversation embedded which reads uglier, can mess up Reply To email addresses etc.
2. Drag&drop the emails in some **IMAP client** from one inbox to another. This properly moves the emails but I haven't found a good IMAP client to be honest - something like Thunderbird will start downloading everything from my inboxes which is a behavior I wasn't able to suppress.

I think the ideal solution would be some "web-based IMAP client" that would allow me to connect both of my inboxes and then do drag&drop on the web, without the need of installing any temporary software locally on my desktop.

Comment: You can configure thunderbird not to download all your emails by default.