# How to move messages from an old Gmail account to a new one?

Tags: gmail

I would like to transfer all of my messages from my old Gmail account to my new Gmail account.

I have followed the steps here: [Automatically forward Gmail messages to another account](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957?hl=en)

However, only the new messages are transferred. Can some one help please?

Comment: Use a desktop client, configure both accounts for imap, then copy and paste the email from the old account to the new account then when happy delete the emails from the old account

Comment: [How to move emails between Gmail accounts?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/84404/354)

Answer (score 2):

The procedure you referenced in your question only forwards new messages you are looking for a procedure that will also bring over the oold messages: The are several questions/answers on the gmail help forum.

here is one:[How do I transfer all of my emails from one gmail account to another?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/KhjfvZybyOQ;context-place=topicsearchin/gmail/transfer$20all$20messages)

the summary of the procedure is :

1) Enable POP on the old account and select for all messages.
2) In the new account in settings/Accounts and import "Add a POP3 mail account you own"
3) A key piece of information is how to log into the account:

> POP Server: pop.gmail.com
>   Port: 995
>   Uncheck: Leave a copy of retrieved message on the server.
>   Check: Always use a secure connection (SSL) when retrieving mail.
>   Uncheck/Check:Label incoming messages – Check it if you want to Label
>   the messages.
>   Uncheck/Check: Archive incoming messages – Check it if you want to archive > messages instead of sending them to the Inbox.

Comment: how to move only the part of emails?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft Outlook to do this:

1. Install Microsoft Outlook.
2. Open Outlook, log on to the two Gmail accounts.
3. Now you will see the Gmail labels showing up as folders on the left. Select all the emails in your old account's folders(hold command or shift when selecting multiple), click "Move" on the menu bar, and select the destination folder/label of your new account.
4. Refresh and give it a day to update the new update on Google's server.